# How to install pre-compiled Ruby 2.0 on Raspbian?

Tags: apt, ruby

I am usually recommend to people who want to install Ruby to use something like [RVM](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) (my preference). However, I'm in the process of installing Ruby from source (using rbenv) and it has taken over an hour and still isn't finished. I'm just wondering if there is a faster way to get Ruby 2.0 installed. Maybe there is some apt package that provides this?

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question yet?

Answer (score 1):

`rbenv install` may take a long time (mine is about 2 to 3 hours), you can just let it run in background and returns to check the installation log in `/tmp/` folder later.

I followed the instructions on [rbenv website.](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) For step 2 and 3, I use:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: I know this will probably work for installing from source, but I'm wondering how/if this can be pre-compiled for future installations.

Comment: This answer explains one aspect of how to set up rbenv on the RPi, not how to get a precompiled version of ruby for/within rbenv.